# Social Engine get user id from profile page

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

I'm trying to add some features to the users profile page, and for that I would need that users ID - just to clarify, it's not viewers ID I'm chasing, it's the ID of the user whose profile I'm viewing.
So, I used `$subject = Engine_Api::_()->core()->getSubject('user');` and it returns a big object full of all kinds of data, but don't know how to extract user ID?

Anyone have a clue? (SocialEngine 4 is the platform I'm using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will get you the userid of the profile..

```
$profileownerid = Engine_Api::_()->core()->getSubject('user')->getIdentity();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out: `$subject_id = $subject->getIdentity();` and voila!